# How should I structure my rss feed pulling site to make the site load quick?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, codeigniter, rss

My site daisy.camorada.com is running a very slow. The reason that it is running slow is that I am pulling multiple RSS feeds to create each masonry  that shows on the page.

My question for you people is basically, How should I structure my site to make it fast, efficient, and scalable?

I have thought about using Code Igniter to put the RSS feeds into a database and then pull from that database anytime the page is refreshed. How would I do this?

Here is a picture of the structure that I am thinking of:

[image: structure that I am thinking of]

Here is the current PHP code that is pulling the feeds (I know it is VERY messy, sorry):
https://gist.github.com/3506863

Comment: Well, at least it's not a cocktail napkin... Are you pulling those feeds every time the feed presentation page is viewed?

Comment: @MarcB, some of the best plans start out on cocktail napkins ;)

Comment: @jakub: true. makes me wonder how many great ideas were lost because someone wiped their nose with that napkin, then forgot the idea in the morning after the hangover wore off.

Comment: LOL! cocktail napkin. @Marc B Yes. I am pulling the feeds every time the page is viewed.

Comment: Hey! Stop dissing coctail napkins - some of the best ideas took off of these... napkin pseudo-coding really can put things into perspective, as shown by the database iconography so skilfully used :) My jsbin/jsfiddle alternative shall be hailed napcode :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres how you can cache your feeds onto your file system, no db required, and pull from there for a curtain amount of time, it will considerably speed up your app. Perhaps its of some interest.

```
<?php 
//Have a list of feeds
$feeds = array(
'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss',
'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=breakingnews',
'http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/pop_top.xml',
'http://news.yahoo.com/rss',
);

$cache_for = 3600; //in seconds
$feed_results = array();

/**
 * Loop through each feed and check if its age is older then $cache_for
 * Grab the feed and store in ./feeds_data
 * On next refresh feed is pulled from cache until $cache_for expires
 */
foreach($feeds as $feed){
    if(cache(sha1($feed), 'check', null, './feeds_data', $cache_for) == false){
        $result = curl_get($feed);
        $feed_result[$feed] = cache(sha1($feed), 'put', $result, './feeds_data', $cache_for);
    }else{
        $feed_result[$feed] = cache(sha1($feed), 'get', null, './feeds_data', $cache_for);
    }
}

//Loop through each feed result and render
foreach($feed_result as $result){
    render_feed_newz_caption($result);
}

//The curl function, curl is considerably faster then fopen that simplexml_load_file uses
function curl_get($url){
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0 Firefox/5.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}

function cache($key, $do, $result=null, $storepath, $cacheTime=86400){
    switch($do){
        case "check":
            if(file_exists($storepath.'/'.sha1($key).'.php')){
                if((time() - $cacheTime < filemtime($storepath.'/'.sha1($key).'.php'))){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
            break;
        case "put":
            //Compress
            $compressed = gzdeflate($result,  9);
            $compressed = gzdeflate($compressed, 9);
            file_put_contents($storepath.'/'.sha1($key).'.php', base64_encode($compressed));
            return $result;
            break;
        case "get":
            $cache = base64_decode(file_get_contents($storepath.'/'.sha1($key).".php"));
            //De-compress
            $compressed = gzinflate($cache);
            $compressed = gzinflate($compressed);
            return $compressed;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }
}



//Function to wrap your parse
function render_feed_newz_caption($feed){
    //load XML string!
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    if(isset($xml->channel->item))
    foreach($xml->channel->item as $YODEL){
        $title = $YODEL->title;
        $description = $YODEL->description;
        $link = $YODEL->link;
        $pubDate = $YODEL->pubDate;     //should be able to use Rutgers pubDate to sort newest.... get a better Drudge feed to do the same
        $image = $YODEL->image;
        //echo"<div class ='masonry_item' style='background: #FFFFFF;'><a href='". $link ."'>" . "RUT: " . $pubDate . "<br />" . $title . "</a> <!--" . $description . "--></div> <br>";

        echo "
    <div class='box'>
        <div class ='newz_caption' style='background: #FFFFFF;'> 
            <h3>"  . $title . "</h3>
            <h5>CNN: "  . $pubDate . "</h5>
            <p>     " . $description .  "   </p>
            <p>
                <a class='btn btn-primary' href='" . $link . "'>    Source  </a>
                    <a class='btn' href='#'>Thumbs Up </a>
            </p>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <br>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH! That is a very cool approach that I hadn't thought about. 
I am getting a few warnings when I run your code here:
http://daisy.camorada.com/aug28index.php

So If I understand your code properly:
1-Checks if feed in cache is newer
2-If newer, updates feed
3- Renders news feed

WOW! Thanks so much for your code! That is an amazing approach to the problem!

So Can you tell me a little more about this method of caching and its advantages over using a DB / other method of caching?

Comment: np, The `render_feed_newz_caption($feed)` function is really only for an example when I was testing. You would perhaps need to make a couple of functions to fit each feed and then add the function type within the $feeds array so you can add different output. Basically, a remote grab of a file is expensive and slow, its faster to cache the result and use that for content that is not updated alot (this type of caching is typically called a dirty cache but its also very simple, check, grab, store repeat), if you get 1k hits per min on your site say, its going to save a huge amount of bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks again Lawrence I can't thank you enough.
Does the caching affect the browser? I've noticed that the proposed caching setup is making the site crash on iOS Safari.
Maybe it could be the error with the `put` case:


`file_put_contents($storepath.'/'.sha1($key).'.php', base64_encode($compressed));`

I'll try and read up a little more on what you've referenced with the simple check grab store model. THANKS! much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

*Props for using CodeIgniter, I hate seeing people build from the ground up without a framework to alleviate boilerplate code.*

Look into setting up a **CRONJOB** or **windows task scheduler**, and have a CONTROLLER that handles fetching your RSS feeds (and some form of caching).

You can SIMPLY cache them using the built in **CI cache** or do it as you describe by storing the **text in your DB**.

How to run your cronjob via CLI: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html

Or you can just look for an existing CI library to do the caching / fetching for you:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/160394/

Comment: THANKS! I hadn't thought of using CI that extensively for this project. Good call.

Which of the two options (db vs. caching) is faster / more scaleable?

Comment: They both work in their own ways, CI's caching is simply making a plain text file in `/application/cache`. Your DB is well.. a DB it can be used for this and other things. Its a tough question for 'scale-ability' as you would need to define expected growth, concurrent users, etc;

Comment: I'll look into this a little bit further. Thanks for your feedback @Jakub!

Answer (score 3):

From my experience in runninng RSS large scale aggregators.

I higly recommend that you use [SimplePie](http://www.simplepie.org/). It makes your work drastically easier.
It has caching mechanisim built in, so you can serve a cache to the home page while storing the content you want in your database.

SimplePie also has built in [like-wordpress functions,](http://www.simplepie.org/wiki/reference/start#feed-level_data_basic) that get the title, content, timestamp...etc. It also lets you mix multiple RSS feeds into one.

Sorry the answer ended up being about simplepie, but it's one of the best choices I've made when I ran those sites.

Comment: don't apologize for a great answer my friend! thanks!!

So would the cache just be on the server and on refresh my mainpage would just pull from the cache as opposed to getting all of the feeds itself? 

By your model, how should i differentiate between caching w/ SimplePie and pulling from a Db?

Comment: Yes, the cache will be on your server in a folder you specify. You can adjust how long the cache should last, so when you refresh your page cache will be served. Since your home page will be the most visited you can give it a time like 10-20 mins or whatever. If you have a single post page, you can read your db.

Comment: Interesting take, I'll look into SimplePie a bit more. I am actually doing some web crawling to pull some the images on the site as well, Because the images are NOT in the RSS feeds that I am pulling from, I'll have to find out if SimplePie does that as well. Thanks for the Suggestion Andrew! Much Appreciated

Comment: No problem, and Yes you can get images.